# C++ debugger_hook_dummy throws exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, exception

I am trying to debug an application and one day it suddenly started doing this, having been previously working:

```
__declspec(noinline)
void __cdecl _CRT_DEBUGGER_HOOK(int _Reserved)
{
/* assign 0 to _debugger_hook_dummy so that the function is not folded
in retail */
(_Reserved);
_debugger_hook_dummy = 0;
}
```

The application then cannot start.

I have read that this is related to dependencies; I do have multiple dll dependencies but they all compile correctly and I have ensured that they are all compiled in the same mode. I have tried in both release and debug mode and I get the same error above.

Any ideas would be extremely helpful as I would love to have a proper debugger again.

Comment: Somebody please answer

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it turned out to be that there was too many bytes on the stack (in debug mode only) which resulted in program counter corruption and eventually this error.  Visual Studio 2010 wasn't reporting the error as stack overflow but once I reduced the bytes on the stack the problem went away.